# Substring in a variable outputs Categoryinfo error

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that that ask a user for its input. The example is below

```
$string = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the string"
$stringTwo = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter another string
```

I then have a variable that combines the two.

```
$combination = $string.Substring(0,3) + $string2.Substring(0,1)
```

This is the error I get

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: That error will appear depending on what you enter at the prompts. If either the first string is less than 3 characters or the second string is less than a single character, you will get this error (read the error message carefully).

Comment: When you say ***combine*** what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: thank you @Bill_Stewart

Comment: I also encourage you to revisit your previous questions and accept answers there, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from an exception in the [`System.String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Substring) .NET method and indicates that either the start index for the substring extraction is outside the range of actual characters in the string or fewer than the requested number of characters are present starting at that index.

E.g., `'foo'.Substring(3)` triggers an error, because `2` is the highest character index in the string, and so does `'foo'.Substring(0, 4)` because the string has only 3 characters (starting at index `0`)

---

Workarounds:

```
$str = 'foo'
$str.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($str.Length, 4)) # ->'foo'
```

However, this gets cumbersome with non-zero start indices.

---

You can write a **helper function**, such as `Get-Substring`, which **returns as many of the requested characters as possible, and defaults to the empty string for a start index that is out of range**:

```
function Get-Substring {
  param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $String,
   [Parameter(Mandatory)] [uint] $StartIndex,
   [uint] $Length = [uint]::MaxValue
  )
  if ($StartIndex -ge $String.Length) { return "" }
  if ($StartIndex + $Length -ge $String.Length) { $Length = $String.Length - $StartIndex }
  $String.Substring($StartIndex, $Length)
}
```

You would then call it as follows:

```
$combination = (Get-Substring $string 0 3) + (Get-Substring $string 0 1)
```

Or, with *named* parameters:

```
$combination = (Get-Substring -String $string -StartIndex 0 -Length 3) # + ...
```

---

**If you prefer a *method***, you can use [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata) to add a `.LaxSubstring()` method to all `[string]` instances:

```
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.String -MemberName SubstringLax -MemberType ScriptMethod  -Value { 
  param([uint] $startIndex, [uint] $length = [uint]::MaxValue)
  if ($startIndex -ge $this.Length) { return "" }
  elseif ($startIndex -lt 0) { $startIndex = 0 }
  if ($startIndex + $length -ge $this.Length) { $length = $this.Length - $startIndex }
  $this.Substring($startIndex, $length)
}
```

Note that this method will only be available in the current session, not persistently.

You would then call it as follows:

```
$combination = $string.SubstringLax(0, 3) + $string2.SubstringLax(0, 1)
```